# Print output into a file or not print output?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'd like to save or ignore outputs when I execute a specific function in lisp. I use Emacs and CCL. For example,

```
(defun foo (x) (format t "x = ~s~%" x))
```

and if I execute the function, it prints out "x = 5". But I don't want to printout in a buffer, because if I have a large amount of iteration, the speed of simulation will be decreased.

Any idea?

Comment: The question is unclear and `(format t ...)` doesn't look valid, is that elisp or Clojure or...?

Comment: (format t ...) is Common Lisp, not elisp. I don't think this really has anything to do with Emacs.

Answer (score 8):

You can temporarily redirect standard output by binding `*standard-output*` to a stream.  For example, a [broadcast stream](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_broadc.htm) with no output streams will serve as a black hole for output:

```
(let ((*standard-output* (make-broadcast-stream)))
  (foo 10)
  (foo 20))
;; Does not output anything.
```

You can also do this with other binding constructs, such as `with-output-to-string` or `with-open-file`:

```
(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
  (foo 10)
  (foo 20))
;; Does not print anything;
;; returns the output as a string instead.

(with-open-file (*standard-output* "/tmp/foo.txt" :direction :output)
  (foo 10)
  (foo 20))
;; Does not print anything;
;; writes the output to /tmp/foo.txt instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `t` as the first argument to `format`, you can give it an output file stream and your output for that statement will be sent to that file stream.

However having excessive disk I/O will also will increase your running time, hence you can consider having two modes like a debug and a release mode for your program where the debug mode prints all the diagnostic messages and the release mode does not print anything at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But what I really want is, like a C program, you can run a program like foo > a.txt, if so the output is printed in a.txt file. I am wondering is there any way to do this in lisp.

Comment: After you compile your code you still can redirect your executable's standard output using `a.txt`. 

Another way would be to call the interpreter like `clisp >a.txt` . That way all the REPL and your standard output will be redirected to `a.txt`

Comment: loudandclear, I don't quite understand your comment. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: If you compile your code and create an executable, called `myexecutable`, then you can redirect the output to a file by calling `myexecutable >a.txt`. 

If you don't want compilation, but want to send your output to a file, then either use Matthias Benkard's solution or start your interpreter (it is `clisp` in this example) as: `clisp >a.txt` and everything including the REPL will be written to `a.txt`

If you don't want to write everything including REPL, only `format` expressions then you can call format as: (format *error-output* "something") and invoke your interpreter as "clisp 2>a.txt"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but the second argument to `format` is a [stream](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm#format). If you set it to `t` it prints to standard output, but you can also set it to an open file.

So something like this would allow you to select where the output goes:

```
;;output to file:
(setf *stream* (open "myfile" :direction :output
                              :if-exists :supersede)

;;alternative to output to standard output:
;;(setf *stream* t)

(defun foo (x) (format *stream* "x = ~s~%" x))

(foo 10)
(close *stream*) ;; only if output sent to a file
```